# Why does the array return a random boolean during the enumeration of the full_name, but not in ruby console? irb

Tags: ruby, irb

Why does the array ( within the map block ) only return [true, true, false] if executed in ruby console as: x = [(rand 2)==1, (rand 5)==3, (rand 11)==6] then x, x, x?

```
first = "stephanie"
last = "devenport"
middle = "Lbp"

full_name = "#{first} #{middle} #{last}"

puts "#{full_name}\s\s\s\s\s"
.rstrip.gsub(' ', '').split(//)
.map{ |char| [(rand 2)==1, (rand 5)==3, (rand 11)==6].any? ? "#{char + ['~', '%', '^', '#'].sample}" : "#{char.upcase + ['-', '_'].sample}" }.join.chop
```

run within terminal returns => S_t~e~p~h#A_n~i^E_L_b~P-d~e^v#E_n%p~o~R-T

Comment: Can you be more specific about the component here that's not working as expected?

Comment: This is working as expected if ran in terminal, ie: ruby string_fundamentals.rb. My question is, if we run just x = [(rand 2)==1, (rand 5)==3, (rand 11)==6] in ruby console it returns => [true, true, false] each & every time we call x... why?

Comment: Rather than beginning lines that follow a newline with a period (which is fine with command-line Ruby), insert the period at the end of the line, before the newline. That tells IRB that the statement is being chained to the next line. Without the period at the end of the line, IRB (and I assume PRY), due to its interactive nature, does not realize the the line is being chained. IRB simply disregards periods that begin lines.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but my code does not contain a semicolon after the initial interpolation string. Plus I am not doing puts in console, just x = [(rand 2)==1, (rand 5)==3, (rand 11)==6] then x, x, x etc...

Comment: My comment has nothing to do with semicolons. Remember: when using IRB, put periods at the end, rather than beginning, of lines

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
x = [(rand 2)==1, (rand 5)==3, (rand 11)==6]
```

This constructs an array with three elements and stores it in `x`. The values in that array are random, but they are determined *when the array is constructed*. Whenever you look at `x` it will always be the same three element array, because the random calls have already been made and the result has been stored in the array.

The problem is that `x` is just a pointer to some values in memory. You can't "call" it. To get a different result every time, you need x to be a method

```
def x
  [(rand 2)==1, (rand 5)==3, (rand 11)==6]
end
```

Comment: Thank you very much, kind regards Michael.

Comment: Cookie, this could be generalized to `def x(arr); arr.map { |a,b| rand(a) == b }; end`, so `x([[2,1],[5,3],[11,6]]) #=> [true, false, false]`, `x([[2,1],[5,3],[11,6],[3,1]]) #=> => [true, false, false, false]`,

Comment: Cary, I loved this test approach so much I implemented the construct within a method which takes 4 standard arguments: def manipulate_string(str, arr, tru, fal) return str.strip.gsub(' ', '').split(//).map{ |char| query = arr.map{ |t,f| rand(t)==f }; query.any? ? "#{char + tru.sample}" : "#{char.upcase + fal.sample}" }.join.chop end Thank you.